# using Primefaces poll to open dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, javabeans

I'm trying to use Primefaces' poll feature to open a dialog box every 30 seconds.  I previously got the poll to call a growl and show some data, but for some reason even though the code to open the dialog has been called, the dialog box just doesn't open.

I know the backing bean function to open the dialog works because I tested it with a button instead of poll, so I'm not sure exactly what is happening here.

Here is where I am calling poll:

```
<p:poll interval="30" listener="#{eventBean.openNote}" />
```

And here is my code in the backing bean:

```
public void openNote() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.openDialog("notedisplay");

}
```

Here is the code I used when testing it with a button:

```
<p:commandLink id="btnSearch" value="Event"
                                actionListener="#{eventBean.openNote}"
                                style="margin-right:10px">
                            </p:commandLink>
```

Comment: `p:poll` submits the form around it, so first of all make sure there is no validation that is silently failing. Without an `update` attribute you won't see any changes to the form even if validation does fail. Is there anything else in the same h:form?

Comment: Maybe I mis-understood the usage of poll, I am basically hoping to use it as a substitute for a button click in order to open a dialog.

Comment: It works almost exactly like an invisible p:commandButton - which includes submitting form data. That's not necessarily your problem but it would help if we could rule it out. Can you also provide the button code that was working for comparison?

Comment: I added the code I used when testing it with a button